# Colorized comments in Katalon Studio

Tags: comments, web-testing, katalon-studio

Is it possible to make a comment in katalon studio colored ? Like how Warning looks yellow , Error looks Red and so?

Comment: Ah, okay then. I have also another question, should I post it or may I ask you ?

Comment: Sure, ask if it is connected with this topic. If not, you can open a new question.

Comment: I have question about katalon studio, but not about comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can change some color preferences in Preferences > Run/Debug > Console:

- Standard Out text color
- Standard Error text color
- Standard In text color
- Bacground color